# ES6 / lodash - check nested Object values with startsWith

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

is there any function or any fast way to check if some value in our object startsWith e.g **asd**

Example:

```
let obj = { 
   'child' : {
      'child_key': 'asdfghhj'
    },
    'free': 'notasd',
    'with': 'asdhaheg'
  }

// check here if our obj has value that startsWith('asd')
```

Regards

Comment: What output you expect? A boolean?

Comment: Yes it can be boolean. Actually it doesn't matter, but that would be the best

Comment: Is the object always this shape?

Comment: I assume you mean to do a deep search? Or are you only search values of the input object?

Comment: Deep search. Real object is much bigger with more nested properties and different keys

Comment: Will it contain any arrays, and if so should those values also be searched?

Comment: No, no arrays. Only normaly Key: value, or key: object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively iterate object properties and check if property starts with `prefix` using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function:

```
function hasPropertyStartingWith(obj, prefix) {
  return !!Object.keys(obj).find(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      return hasPropertyStartingWith(obj[key], prefix)
    }
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
      return obj[key].startsWith(prefix)
    }
    return false
  })
}

console.log(hasPropertyStartingWith(obj, 'asd'))
```

Comment: @crotoan, maybe it is not applicable to your actual case, but this code generates an error when one of the property values happens to be `null` or `undefined`, nor does it detect that a numerical value can start with something like '1' or '-'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function with mild ES6 usage:

```js
function startsWithRecursive(obj, needle) {
    return obj != null && 
        (typeof obj === "object"
            ? Object.keys(obj).some( key => startsWithRecursive(obj[key], needle) )
            : String(obj).startsWith(needle));
}

// Sample data
let obj = { 
    'child' : {
      'child_key': 'asdfghhj'
    },
    'free': 'notasd',
    'with': 'asdhaheg'
};
// Requests
console.log( 'obj, "asd":',    startsWithRecursive(obj, 'asd'    ) );
console.log( 'obj, "hello":',  startsWithRecursive(obj, 'hello'  ) );
console.log( 'null, "":',      startsWithRecursive(null, ''      ) );
console.log( 'undefined, "":', startsWithRecursive(undefined, '' ) );
console.log( '"test", "te":',  startsWithRecursive('test', 'te'  ) );
console.log( '12.5, 1:',       startsWithRecursive(12.5, 1       ) );
```

#### Explanation:

The function is recursive: it calls itself as it goes through a nested object structure. The value passed as `obj` can fall in one of the following three categories:

1. It is equivalent to `null` (like also `undefined`): in that case neither a recursive call, nor a call of the `startsWith` method can be made: the result is `false` as this value obviously does not start with the given search string;
2. It is an object: in that case that object's property values should be inspected. This will be done through recursive calls. The `some` method makes sure that as soon a match has been found, the iteration stops, and no further property values are inspected. In that case `some` returns `true`. If none of the property values matched, `some` returns `false`;
3. It is none of the above. In that case we cast it to string (by applying the `String` function) and apply `startsWith` on it.

The value calculated in the applicable step will be returned as function result. If this was a recursive call, it will be treated as return value in the `some` callback, ...etc.

Note that this function also returns the correct result when you call it on a string, like so:

```
startsWithRecursive('test', 'te'); // true
```

#### Non-Recursive Alternative

In answer to comments about potential stack limitations, here is an alternative non-recursive function which maintains a "stack" in a variable:

```
function startsWithRecursive(obj, needle) {
    var stack = [obj];
    while (stack.length) {
        obj = stack.pop();
        if (obj != null) {
            if (typeof obj === "object") {
                stack = stack.concat(Object.keys(obj).map( key => obj[key] ));
            } else {
                if (String(obj).startsWith(needle)) return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Very nice that this works with Array child nodes although I'm not sure if it was intentional or just a lucky side effect ^_^

Comment: In JavaScript arrays are objects (`typeof` "object") with some additional features (like a `length` property), so yes, it is intended to work for arrays.

Comment: One thing to note about recursion, the stack is finite and with very large objects you can hit a limit.

Comment: @Xotic750 to be more specific, objects with very deep levels of nesting could hit a limit. A flat object, or even an object with hundreds of levels of nesting with thousands of keys would be fine.

Comment: Very nice. I wasn't suggesting that it was a must, just a note. But very good. ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Use @trincot's solution if you really don't care about which node/value matched. It's straightforward, well-written, and solves your problem very effectively.

If you want more than just a Boolean value as the result of your digging, read along ...

---

I really doubt your need for this, but if your object is significantly large, you will want an **early exit behaviour** – what this means is that as soon as a match is found, iteration through your input data will stop and `true`/`false` result will be returned immediately. @trincot's solution offers early exit, but solutions that using `map`, `filter`, or `reduce` offer no such behaviour.

`findDeep` is much more useful than just checking if a string value starts with another string value – it takes a higher-order function that is applied for each leaf node in your data.

This answer uses my `findDeep` procedure to define a generic `anyStartsWith` procedure by checking if `findDeep` returns `undefined` (no match)

It will work any any input type and it will traverse `Object` and `Array` child nodes.

```js
const isObject = x=> Object(x) === x
const isArray = Array.isArray
const keys = Object.keys
const rest = ([x,...xs]) => xs

const findDeep = f => x => {
  
  let make = (x,ks)=> ({node: x, keys: ks || keys(x)})
  
  let processNode = (parents, path, {node, keys:[k,...ks]})=> {
    if (k === undefined)
      return loop(parents, rest(path))
    else if (isArray(node[k]) || isObject(node[k]))
      return loop([make(node[k]), make(node, ks), ...parents], [k, ...path])
    else if (f(node[k], k))
      return {parents, path: [k,...path], node}
    else
      return loop([{node, keys: ks}, ...parents], path)
  }
  
  let loop = ([node,...parents], path) => {
    if (node === undefined)
      return undefined
    else
      return processNode(parents, path, node)
  }
  
  return loop([make(x)], [])
}

const startsWith = x => y => y.indexOf(x) === 0
const anyStartsWith = x => xs => findDeep (startsWith(x)) (xs) !== undefined

let obj = { 
  'child' : {
    'child_key': 'asdfghhj'
  },
  'free': 'notasd',
  'with': 'asdhaheg'
}

console.log(anyStartsWith ('asd') (obj))   // true
console.log(anyStartsWith ('candy') (obj)) // false
```

---

You'll see this is kind of a waste of `findDeep`'s potential, but if you don't need it's power then it's not for you.

Here's the real power of `findDeep`

```
findDeep (startsWith('asd')) (obj)

// =>     
{
  parents: [
    {
      node: {
        child: {
          child_key: 'asdfghhj'
        },
        free: 'notasd',
        with: 'asdhaheg'
      },
      keys: [ 'free', 'with' ]
    }
  ],
  path: [ 'child_key', 'child' ],
  node: {
    child_key: 'asdfghhj'
  }
}
```

The resulting object has 3 properties

- `parents` – the full object reference to each node in the matched value's lineage
- `path` – the path of keys to get to the matched value (stack reversed)
- `node` – the key/value pair that matched

You can see that if we take the parent object as `p` and reverse the path stack, we get to the matched value

```
p['child']['child_key']; //=> 'asdfghhj'
```

Comment: As you referred to my answer, I wonder: are you suggesting the solution I propose does not make an early exit when a match is found?

Comment: @trincot no, not at all. I will make an update to be more explicit about that.

Comment: Ah, sorry for my misunderstanding... I read it again, and indeed I made a wrong connection there ;-)

Comment: @trincot my original answer didn't mention yours. When I added the bit at the top, I wasn't careful enough to separate the two distinct things I was trying to communicate. <3

Answer (score 0):

You may get away with something as simple as using a RegExp on a JSON string, something like

```js
var obj = {
  'child': {
    'child_key': 'asdfghhj'
  },
  'free': 'notasd',
  'with': 'asdhaheg'
};

function customStartsWith(obj, prefix) {
  return new RegExp(':"' + prefix + '[\\s\\S]*?"').test(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

console.log('obj, "asd":', customStartsWith(obj, 'asd'));
console.log('obj, "hello":', customStartsWith(obj, 'hello'));
console.log('null, "":', customStartsWith(null, ''));
console.log('undefined, "":', customStartsWith(undefined, ''));
console.log('"test", "te":', customStartsWith('test', 'te'));
console.log('12.5, 1:', customStartsWith(12.5, 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.1/es6-shim.js"></script>
```

Update: Another recursive object walker that will work in a shimmed environment. This is just an example and it is easily customised.

```js
var walk = returnExports;
var obj = {
  'child': {
    'child_key': 'asdfghhj'
  },
  'free': 'notasd',
  'with': 'asdhaheg'
};

function customStartsWith(obj, prefix) {
  var found = false;
  walk(obj, Object.keys, function(value) {
    if (typeof value === 'string' && value.startsWith(prefix)) {
      found = true;
      walk.BREAK;
    }
  });
  return found;
}

console.log('obj, "asd":', customStartsWith(obj, 'asd'));
console.log('obj, "hello":', customStartsWith(obj, 'hello'));
console.log('null, "":', customStartsWith(null, ''));
console.log('undefined, "":', customStartsWith(undefined, ''));
console.log('"test", "te":', customStartsWith('test', 'te'));
console.log('12.5, 1:', customStartsWith(12.5, 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.1/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/Xotic750/object-walk-x/master/lib/object-walk-x.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice idea! You'd need to escape special regex characters in `prefix` though, and deal with backslashes or unicode escapes in the JSON string.

Comment: Yeah, this is certainly not production ready code, more the idea. :)